# is it possible to do multiple activitycount check in teradata?

Tags: teradata, bteq

using bteq script, I want to delete the temporary error and log tables created during TPT load namely ErrorTable1, ErrorTable2, LogTable.

I have prepared following bteq script with if-else, which will drop tables if it exists

```
.LOGON ${HOST}/${USER},${PASS};

SELECT 1 FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE CONCAT(DataBaseName, '.', TableName) = 'Test.ErrorTable1';
.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN GOTO CHECK_1;
DROP TABLE Test.ErrorTable1;


.LABEL CHECK_1;
SELECT 1 FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE CONCAT(DataBaseName, '.', TableName) = 'Test.ErrorTable2';
.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN GOTO CHECK_2;
DROP TABLE Test.ErrorTable2;


.LABEL CHECK_2;
SELECT 1 FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE CONCAT(DataBaseName, '.', TableName) = 'Test.LogTable';
.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN GOTO DONE;
DROP TABLE Test.LogTable;


.LABEL DONE;

.LOGOFF
.EXIT
```

My question is, in teradata bteq, can I use ACTIVITYCOUNT multiple times, like in above script, to check various table's existence?

Comment: Of course, AVTIVITYCOUNT is reset with every SQL statement. But you might simplify your logic to `.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN DROP TABLE Test.ErrorTable2;` or use a Storerd Procedure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771103/2527905

Comment: Thanks fred and dnoeth

Comment: Correcting earlier incorrect comment: Though `CONCAT` function is now supported, the ANSI concatenation operator `||` is preferred.

Comment: Also note that (though not needed for this case) current versions of BTEQ support "multi-instruction" `.IF` `.ELSEIF` `.ELSE` `.ENDIF` blocks (which can be nested) in addition to `.IF ... THEN` single-instruction syntax.

Comment: Thanks Fred can you point me to some example snippet of IF, ELSEIF, ELSE etc.  usage in bteq script, I do not really wish to do GOTO if full-blown if-else-if is supported by bteq in teradata